# I want to enable userChrome.css | I want to edit my my default appearance of Firefox UI

Tags: firefox, css

So I've just moved from Windows to Ubuntu 20.04 as my main driver. I had no issue finding my desired applications to run natively (tusk as Evernote client, Notion client, Mega cloud sync) so I had no issues with my new Ubuntu PC until I found this to be quite challenging...

I'm running latest Firefox available as of writing, I just installed it through apt-get package manager. I had no browser or usability issue so far. But, I just want to hide following options like 'Addons', 'Customize', Edit and Zoom options from the hamburger menu.

So, I opened the Profile folder through Troubleshooting menu, I created following steps religiously...

Created 'chrome' folder onto Profile, I made 'userChrome.css' file under that directory and written following code (which was working fine on my Windows machine).

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");

#appMenu-addons-button, #addonsButton, #appMenu-preferences-button, #appMenu-zoom-controls, #appMenu-edit-controls, #appMenu-customize-button {
display: none !important;
}
```

Of course, I set the following option 'toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets' value to true and tried a couple of variations on the link of namespace url.

I also tried the following:

```
u/namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only");
```

None of them had any noticeable change onto my Firefox default UI. So, I just wanna hide following items as I mentioned above. So, I hope you could walk me through steps to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 1):

**Delete** all the files or folders that you have created before.
Find the correct `"Profile Folder Path"` opening Firefox → *Menu* → *Help* → *TroubleShooting* → in the field *Profile Directory*.

Go to `"Profile Folder Path"` and create a new folder named chrome:

```
cd "Profile Folder Path"
mkdir chrome
```

Now you have a path `"Profile Folder Path"/chrome/`, create a file named `userChrome.css`

```
cd "Profile Folder Path"/chrome/
nano chrome/userChrome.css
```

Paste this text to remove bars and test it:

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"); /* only needed once */
#PanelUI-menu-button {display: none;}
#TabsToolbar {visibility: collapse;}
#navigator-toolbox {visibility: collapse;}
browser {margin-right: -14px; margin-bottom: -14px;}
```

Check the access rights (**No root user here**):

```
drwxrwxr-x   user1 user1 chrome/
-rw-rw-r--   user1 user1 userChrome.css
```

Close Firefox and open it again, well done!!! I wish it helps...

Answer (score 0):

In a new Tab, open `about:config`. Search for the `privacy.webrtc.legacyGlobalIndicator` setting and toggle it to `false`.

(See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60128378/can-i-stop-the-firefox-webrtc-sharing-indicator-showing-up)